# removing jRadioButton automatically in java

Tags: java, swing, removechild, jradiobutton, buttongroup

I have a set of `JRadioButton`s placed inside a `JPanel`.
Also I have a "delete" button, such that if a `JRadioButton` is selected and then this "delete" button is pressed, the `JRadioButton` should be deleted from the `JPanel`.

I tried this following (action listener for the delete button) but it didn't work.

```
// bg: buttonGroup

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int count = -1;
    for (Enumeration e=bg.getElements(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {
        JRadioButton b = (JRadioButton)e.nextElement();count++;
        if (b.getModel() == bg.getSelection()) {
            bg.remove(b);
            jPanel1.remove(jPanel1.getComponent(count)); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what was the outcome of your try?

Comment: Probably call validate after removing the component.  If that fails, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you call

```
jPanel1.revalidate();
jPanel1.repaint();
```

after deleting?